# How to give a color to the Column Header in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

I have created a telerik RadGrid in asp .net. My requirement is to give my own color to Column header. How can we achieve this...? Below is the code structure I'm using.

```
  <Telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server">
     <MasterTableView Width="100%" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True">

            <DetailTables>
                <telerik:GridTableView DataKeyNames="OrderID" Name="Orders" Width="100%">

                    <DetailTables>
                        <telerik:GridTableView DataKeyNames="OrderID" Name="OrderDetails" Width="100%">
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Unit Price" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="UnitPrice">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Quantity">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </telerik:GridTableView>
                    </DetailTables>

                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="OrderID" HeaderText="OrderID" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="OrderID">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date Ordered" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="OrderDate" UniqueName="OrderDate" DataFormatString="{0:D}">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>

                </telerik:GridTableView>
            </DetailTables>

            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="CustomerID">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="ContactName">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>

        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

And it should looks like image below:
[image]

Comment: I added in a step 0, so make sure you see that. The Grid folder that I'm asking you to include allows your custom css class to mimic the default one from telerik, but make the background adjustment without breaking our custom functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Telerik automatically uses a skin for its grid. If you have not specified a skin it will use the Grid.Default skin. You can modify this skin or any of the skins to your own custom style. Just follow these steps.

- Change the properties in the css file. (The default grid skin is called Grid.Default.css. On my computer it is found in the folder where I have the telerik RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX in the folder Skins\Default.) In this case, change the css something like this:

Grid.Default.css (line 59)

```
.RadGrid_Default .rgHeader,
.RadGrid_Default th.rgResizeCol
{
  border:0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #828282;
  background-color: Red;
  /* background:#eaeaea 0 -2300px repeat-x url('Grid/sprite.gif'); */
}
```

- Add a link to the css file that you modified on the page where you have your grid (or in the master page). `<link href="Grid.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
- Add the property EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" to your RadGrid. `<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" runat="server">` This will tell the page to use your modified css file instead of the embedded one.

Telerik's web site has a blog post called [How To Override Styles in a RadControl for ASP.NET AJAX' Embedded Skin](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/08-06-17/how-to-override-styles-in-a-radcontrol-for-asp-net-ajax-embedded-skin.aspx) that explains in detail how to override an existing style.

Answer (score 1):

We meet again!:

**Step 0: (Added via edit) Navigate to the following install folder and add the grid folder to your project)**

```
C:\Program Files\Telerik\RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Q3 2011\Skins\Default
```

[image]

---

Results of what I managed to produce

[image]

**Step 1: Create a stylesheet, I named mine Grid.Default.css and link it in your .aspx page between the head tags.**

```
<head>
   <link href="Grid.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

**Step 2: Open said style sheet and paste this verbatim:**

```
/*Telerik RadGrid Default Skin*/

/*global*/

.RadGrid_Default
{
    border:1px solid #828282;
    background:#fff;
    color:#333;
}

.RadGrid_Default,
.RadGrid_Default .rgMasterTable,
.RadGrid_Default .rgDetailTable,
.RadGrid_Default .rgGroupPanel table,
.RadGrid_Default .rgCommandRow table,
.RadGrid_Default .rgEditForm table,
.RadGrid_Default .rgPager table,
.GridToolTip_Default
{
    font:12px/16px "segoe ui",arial,sans-serif;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgAdd,
.RadGrid_Default .rgRefresh,
.RadGrid_Default .rgEdit,
.RadGrid_Default .rgDel,
.RadGrid_Default .rgFilter,
.RadGrid_Default .rgPagePrev,
.RadGrid_Default .rgPageNext,
.RadGrid_Default .rgPageFirst,
.RadGrid_Default .rgPageLast,
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpand,
.RadGrid_Default .rgCollapse,
.RadGrid_Default .rgSortAsc,
.RadGrid_Default .rgSortDesc,
.RadGrid_Default .rgUpdate,
.RadGrid_Default .rgCancel,
.RadGrid_Default .rgUngroup,
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpXLS,
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpDOC,
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpPDF,
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpCSV
{
    background-image:url('Grid/sprite.gif');
}

/*header*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgHeaderDiv
{
    background:#eee 0 -7550px repeat-x url('Grid/sprite.gif');
}
.rgTwoLines .rgHeaderDiv
{
    background-position:0 -7050px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgHeader {
    background-color: rgb(236, 89, 91);
}

.RadGrid_Default th.rgResizeCol
{
    border:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #828282;
    background:#eaeaea 0 -2300px repeat-x url('Grid/sprite.gif');
}

.RadGrid_Default th.rgSorted
{
    background-color:#c4c4c4;
    background-position:0 -2600px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgHeader,
.RadGrid_Default .rgHeader a
{
    color:#333;
}

/*rows*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgRow td,
.RadGrid_Default .rgAltRow td,
.RadGrid_Default .rgEditRow td,
.RadGrid_Default .rgFooter td
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0 0 1px 0;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgRow td
{
    border-color:#fff;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgAltRow
{
    background:#f2f2f2;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgAltRow td
{
    border-color:#f2f2f2;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgRow .rgSorted
{
    border-bottom-color:#f2f2f2;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgAltRow .rgSorted
{
    border-bottom-color:#e6e6e6;
    background-color:#e6e6e6;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgSelectedRow .rgSorted,
.RadGrid_Default .rgActiveRow .rgSorted,
.RadGrid_Default .rgHoveredRow .rgSorted,
.RadGrid_Default .rgEditRow .rgSorted
{
    background-color:transparent;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgRow a,
.RadGrid_Default .rgAltRow a,
.RadGrid_Default .rgEditRow a,
.RadGrid_Default tr.rgEditRow a,
.RadGrid_Default tr.rgHoveredRow a,
.RadGrid_Default tr.rgActiveRow a,
.RadGrid_Default .rgFooter a,
.RadGrid_Default .rgEditForm a
{
    color:#000;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgSelectedRow
{
    background:#828282 0 -3900px repeat-x url('Grid/sprite.gif');
    color:#fff;
}
*+html .RadGrid_Default .rgSelectedRow .rgSorted{background-color:#828282}
* html .RadGrid_Default .rgSelectedRow .rgSorted{background-color:#828282}

.RadGrid_Default .rgSelectedRow a
{
    color:#fff;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgActiveRow,
.RadGrid_Default .rgHoveredRow
{
    background:#c5c5c5 0 -2900px repeat-x url('Grid/sprite.gif');
    color:#333;
}
*+html .RadGrid_Default .rgActiveRow .rgSorted,
*+html .RadGrid_Default .rgHoveredRow .rgSorted{background-color:#c5c5c5}
* html .RadGrid_Default .rgActiveRow .rgSorted,
* html .RadGrid_Default .rgHoveredRow .rgSorted{background-color:#c5c5c5}

.RadGrid_Default .rgEditRow
{
    background:#fff 0 -4900px repeat-x url('Grid/sprite.gif');
    color:#333;
}
*+html .RadGrid_Default .rgEditRow .rgSorted{background-color:#fff}
* html .RadGrid_Default .rgEditRow .rgSorted{background-color:#fff}

.RadGrid_Default .rgActiveRow td,
.RadGrid_Default .rgActiveRow td.rgSorted,
.RadGrid_Default .rgHoveredRow td,
.RadGrid_Default .rgHoveredRow td.rgSorted
{
    border-bottom-color:#9e9e9e;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgSelectedRow td,
.RadGrid_Default .rgSelectedRow td.rgSorted
{
    border-bottom-color:#6c6c6c;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgDrag
{
    background-image:url('Grid/rgDrag.gif');
}

/*footer*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgFooterDiv,
.RadGrid_Default .rgFooter
{
    background:#eee;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgFooter td
{
    border-top:1px solid #828282;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}

/*status*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgPager .rgStatus
{
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#828282 #c9c9c9 #eee #c9c9c9;
    border-left-width:0;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgStatus div
{

}

/*pager*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgPager
{
    background:#eee;
}

.RadGrid_Default td.rgPagerCell
{
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#828282 #eee #eee;
    border-right-width:0;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgInfoPart
{
    color:#8a8a8a;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgInfoPart strong
{
    color:#4c4e54;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgPageFirst
{
    background-position:0 -550px;
}
.RadGrid_Default .rgPageFirst:hover
{
    background-position:0 -600px;
}
.RadGrid_Default .rgPagePrev
{
    background-position:0 -700px;
}
.RadGrid_Default .rgPagePrev:hover
{
    background-position:0 -750px;
}
.RadGrid_Default .rgPageNext
{
    background-position:0 -850px;
}
.RadGrid_Default .rgPageNext:hover
{
    background-position:0 -900px;
}
.RadGrid_Default .rgPageLast
{
    background-position:0 -1000px;
}
.RadGrid_Default .rgPageLast:hover
{
    background-position:0 -1050px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgPager .rgPagerButton
{
    border-color:#d0d0d0 #aeaeae #8b8b8b;
    background:#e8e8e8 repeat-x 0 -1550px url('Grid/sprite.gif');
    color:#000;
    font-family:"segoe ui",arial,sans-serif;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a:hover,
.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a:hover span,
.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a.rgCurrentPage,
.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a.rgCurrentPage span
{
    background:no-repeat url('Grid/sprite.gif');
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a
{
    color:#000;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a:hover
{
    background-position:100% -1250px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a:hover span
{
    background-position:0 -1150px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a.rgCurrentPage,
.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a.rgCurrentPage:hover
{
    background-position:100% -1450px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a.rgCurrentPage span,
.RadGrid_Default .rgNumPart a.rgCurrentPage:hover span
{
    background-position:0 -1350px;
}

/*sorting, reordering*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgHeader .rgSortAsc
{
    background-position:3px -248px;
    height:10px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgHeader .rgSortDesc
{
    background-position:3px -198px;
    height:10px;
}

.GridReorderTop_Default,
.GridReorderBottom_Default
{
    background:0 0 no-repeat url('Grid/sprite.gif');
}

.GridReorderBottom_Default
{
    background-position:0 -50px;
}

/*filtering*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgFilterRow
{
    background:#eee;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgFilterRow td
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #828282;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgFilter
{
    background-position:0 -300px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgFilter:hover
{
    background-position:0 -350px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgFilterActive,
.RadGrid_Default .rgFilterActive:hover
{
    background-position:0 -400px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgFilterBox
{
    border-color:#8e8e8e #c9c9c9 #c9c9c9 #8e8e8e;
    font-family:"segoe ui",arial,sans-serif;
    color:#333;
}

/*filter context menu*/

.RadMenu_Default .rgHCMClear,
.RadMenu_Default .rgHCMFilter
{
    border-color:#d0d0d0 #a8a8a8 #8b8b8b;

    color:#000;
    font-family:"segoe ui",arial,sans-serif;
}

.RadMenu_Default .rgHCMClear:hover,
.RadMenu_Default .rgHCMFilter:hover
{
    border-color:#d1d1d1 #b9b9b9 #a3a3a3;
    background-position:center -67px;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
}

/*context menu*/

.GridContextMenu_Default .rmLeftImage
{

}

.GridContextMenu_Default .rgHCMSortAsc .rmLeftImage
{
    background-position:0 0;
}

.GridContextMenu_Default .rgHCMSortDesc .rmLeftImage
{
    background-position:0 -40px;
}

.GridContextMenu_Default .rgHCMUnsort .rmLeftImage
{
    background-position:0 -80px;
}

.GridContextMenu_Default .rgHCMGroup .rmLeftImage
{
    background-position:0 -120px;
}

.GridContextMenu_Default .rgHCMUngroup .rmLeftImage
{
    background-position:0 -160px;
}

.GridContextMenu_Default .rgHCMCols .rmLeftImage
{
    background-position:0 -200px;
}

.GridContextMenu_Default .rgHCMFilter .rmLeftImage
{
    background-position:0 -240px;
}

.GridContextMenu_Default .rgHCMUnfilter .rmLeftImage
{
    background-position:0 -280px;
}

/*grouping*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgGroupPanel
{
    border:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #828282;
    background:#eee 0 -1900px repeat-x url('Grid/sprite.gif');
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgGroupPanel td
{
    border:0;
    padding:3px 4px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgGroupPanel td td
{
    padding:0;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgGroupPanel .rgSortAsc
{
    background-position:4px -144px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgGroupPanel .rgSortDesc
{
    background-position:4px -94px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgUngroup
{
    background-position:0 -6998px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgGroupItem
{
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#c4c4c4 #c4c4c4 #9e9e9e;
    background:#c6c6c6 0 -6500px repeat-x url('Grid/sprite.gif');
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgMasterTable td.rgGroupCol,
.RadGrid_Default .rgMasterTable td.rgExpandCol
{
    border-color:#d9d9d9;
    background:#d9d9d9 none;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgGroupHeader
{
    background:#d9d9d9;
    font-size:1.1em;
    line-height:21px;
    color:#000;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgGroupHeader td
{
    border-top:1px solid #828282;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgGroupHeader td.rgGroupCol
{
    border-top-color:#828282;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgExpand
{
    background-position:5px -496px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgCollapse
{
    background-position:3px -444px;
}

/*editing*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgEditForm
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #828282;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgUpdate
{
    background-position:0 -1800px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgCancel
{
    background-position:0 -1850px;
}

/*hierarchy*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgDetailTable
{
    border-color:#828282;
}

/*command row*/

.RadGrid_Default .rgCommandRow
{
    background:#c5c5c5 0 -2099px repeat-x url('Grid/sprite.gif');
    color:#000;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgCommandCell
{
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#999 #f2f2f2;
    border-top-width:0;
    padding:0;
}

.RadGrid_Default tfoot .rgCommandCell,
.RadGrid_Default .rgMasterTable>tbody>tr.rgCommandRow .rgCommandCell
{
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-bottom-width:0;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgCommandTable td
{
    border:0;
    padding:2px 7px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgCommandTable
{
    border:0;
    border-top:1px solid #fdfdfd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgCommandRow a
{
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgAdd
{
    margin-right:3px;
    background-position:0 -1650px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgRefresh
{
    margin-right:3px;
    background-position:0 -1600px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgEdit
{
    background-position:0 -1700px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgDel
{
    background-position:0 -1750px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgSelected .rgDel
{
    background-position:0 -1775px;
}

.RadGrid_Default .rgExpXLS,
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpDOC,
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpPDF,
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpCSV
{

}

.RadGrid_Default .rgExpXLS
{
    background-position:0 0;
}
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpDOC
{
    background-position:0 -50px;
}
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpPDF
{
    background-position:0 -100px;
}
.RadGrid_Default .rgExpCSV
{
    background-position:0 -150px;
}

/*multirow select*/

.GridRowSelector_Default
{
    background:#4c4e54;
}

/*row drag n drop*/

.GridItemDropIndicator_Default
{
    border-top:1px dashed #666;
}

/*tooltip*/

.GridToolTip_Default
{
    border:1px solid #828282;
    padding:3px;
    background:#fff;
    color:#333;
}

/*rtl*/

.RadGridRTL_Default .rgPageFirst
{
    background-position:0 -1000px;
}
.RadGridRTL_Default .rgPageFirst:hover
{
    background-position:0 -1050px;
}
.RadGridRTL_Default .rgPagePrev
{
    background-position:0 -850px;
}
.RadGridRTL_Default .rgPagePrev:hover
{
    background-position:0 -900px;
}
.RadGridRTL_Default .rgPageNext
{
    background-position:0 -700px;
}
.RadGridRTL_Default .rgPageNext:hover
{
    background-position:0 -750px;
}
.RadGridRTL_Default .rgPageLast
{
    background-position:0 -550px;
}
.RadGridRTL_Default .rgPageLast:hover
{
    background-position:0 -600px;
}

.RadGridRTL_Default .rgExpand
{
    background-position:-20px -496px;
}
```

**Step 3: Go to your grid and set your css class to default and turn off embedded skins:**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" oninit="RadGrid1_Init" 
        onneeddatasource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" CssClass="Default" 
        EnableEmbeddedSkins="False">
```

Step 4: Run it. (If you wish to adjust the color I used, as I tried to get it as close as possible to the one in your screenshot, see below.)

NOTE: To change the color modify this declaration in the css class:

```
.RadGrid_Default .rgHeader 
{
   background-color: rgb(236, 89, 91);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A VERY EASY way to achieve your results is to use...

`<ItemStyle BackColor="Red"/>`

And

`<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="Red"/>`

Here is your code with the tags inserted...

```
  <Telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server">
     <MasterTableView Width="100%" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True">

            <ItemStyle BackColor="Red"/>
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="Red"/>

            <DetailTables>
                <telerik:GridTableView DataKeyNames="OrderID" Name="Orders" Width="100%">

                    <DetailTables>
                        <telerik:GridTableView DataKeyNames="OrderID" Name="OrderDetails" Width="100%">
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Unit Price" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="UnitPrice">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Quantity">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </telerik:GridTableView>
                    </DetailTables>

                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="OrderID" HeaderText="OrderID" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="OrderID">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date Ordered" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="OrderDate" UniqueName="OrderDate" DataFormatString="{0:D}">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>

                </telerik:GridTableView>
            </DetailTables>

            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="CustomerID">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="ContactName">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>

        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and even after overriding the class, the header color did not change.

```
.RadGrid_Default .rgHeader { background-color: rgb(236, 89, 91); }
```

I found that my overridden background was re-overridden by Grid. I used `!important` keyword not to allow Grid to re-override my class

```
.RadGrid_Default .rgHeader { background-color: rgb(236, 89, 91) !important; }
```

Same you can do for any class!