# Telerik Javascript - can it be customized?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I am using Telerik's RadEditor control on a page. It is the only Telerik control in use, but the telerik.web.ui.webresource.axd that is downloaded includes the radwindow javascipt code. I understand RadEditor uses this for some dialogs but my page does not and would like to improve performance by removing this script from telerik.web.ui.webresource.axd.

Is it possible to customize it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the RadEditor control from using embedded web resources by setting UseEmbeddedScripts = false. If you set UseEmbeddedScripts to false, files from the RadControls folder will be used.

For a more detailed explanation see [Disabling embedded resources](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-disabling-embedded-resources.html).

Comment: It seems to have reduced the size of the telerik.web.ui.webresource.axd JS that gets downloaded but it's still there... hmm

Comment: Is the RadWindowScripts.js still showing up? If so, is it using the one in the default direcotry Path="~/Scripts/Window/RadWindowScripts.js"? If so, you could edit out the part you don't want if you are ok with the results of that.

Comment: Yea that is one (of them). Good idea. Have you done that before?

Comment: I've done something similar with a .css file, but not with a .js file. (In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988592/ I have an answer dealing with a .css file.)