# How do I use a custom CSS stylesheet for Telerik?

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I'm using Telerik grids, and want to customize the CSS. I've used Telerik's [stylebuilder](http://stylebuilder.telerik.com/) but I don't know what to do with it once I download the zip. Telerik [says](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/style-builder/visual-style-builder-info.aspx) that I should

> Simply add the files from this archive to your project, and your custom skin is ready go.

But I have no idea where in the project to add them, or even how exactly this is done. I moved the CSS files into the stylesheets folder (I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010) and linked to them, but no dice.

I've also read through [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/style-builder/custom-stylesheets-for-telerik-controls.aspx) [this](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/08-02-28/web-resources-demystified-part-2.aspx) and [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-how-skins-work.html) but am still thoroughly confused.

Comment: The answer I gave at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988592/how-to-give-a-color-to-the-column-header-in-telerik-radgrid may be helpful for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Export theme from style builder, example classic.zip.

   Contents of classic.zip

   - Folder: classic
   - File: telerik.classic.css
2. Extract zip to your project's content folder, c:\path to your project\Content\
3. Modify your master page style sheet regsitrar to include telerik.classic.css instead of the supplied style sheets.

:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
        .DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css")
                                    .Add("telerik.classic.css"))
%>
```

Comment: Did you succeed at integrating your custom css style into the project?

Comment: Eventually someone else found a totally different way to do it, and I have no idea how they did it. :D